# Alarm manager is not working for multiple alarms

Tags: alarmmanager

I am using setalarmclock or setexact both method but alarm manager still not working.
Here is the code for create alarm

```
private static class ScheduleAlarm {
    @NonNull private final Context ctx;
    @NonNull private final AlarmManager am;

    private ScheduleAlarm(@NonNull AlarmManager am, @NonNull Context ctx) {
        this.am = am;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    static ScheduleAlarm with(Context context) {
      final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (am == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AlarmManager is null");
        }
        return new ScheduleAlarm(am, context);
    }

    void schedule(Alarm alarm, PendingIntent pi) {
        if (SDK_INT > LOLLIPOP) {
            am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmClockInfo(alarm.getTime(), launchAlarmLandingPage(ctx,alarm)), pi);
        } else {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTime(), pi);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are providing a unique `requestCode` for each PendingIntent you have. Using the same `requestCode` will result in overriding alarms.